# How to fix error: only a single offscreen document may be created?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My extension use [chrome.offscreen API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/). The main target is run offscreen at startup browser. Seldom and random at startup browser occurs error `Only a single offscreen document may be created`. The extension in such case stop working (content script dont inject elements to site and no error in site console). Only reloading the extension or browser fix problem.

I have check that offscreen document created early 3 ways: with global `isOffscreenCreating` promise, with `chrome.offscreen.hasDocument()` native function and custom `hasOffscreenDocument()`. In fact, the custom `hasOffscreenDocument()` always return false. I dont know why, but it from documentation example.

Do you have suggestion why error happen?

```js
// background.js
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(setupOffscreenDocument)
setupOffscreenDocument()

const OFFSCREEN_DOCUMENT_PATH = 'assets/html/offscreen.html'
let isOffscreenCreating

export async function setupOffscreenDocument() {
    if (isOffscreenCreating) {
        await isOffscreenCreating;
    } else if ((chrome.offscreen.hasDocument && !(await chrome.offscreen.hasDocument())) || !(await hasOffscreenDocument())) {
        try {
            isOffscreenCreating = chrome.offscreen.createDocument({
                url: OFFSCREEN_DOCUMENT_PATH,
                reasons: [chrome.offscreen.Reason.IFRAME_SCRIPTING],
                justification: 'Listening WebSocket messages',
            })
            await isOffscreenCreating;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
        } finally {
            isOffscreenCreating = null
        }
    }
}

async function hasOffscreenDocument() {
    const matchedClients = await clients.matchAll();
    for (const client of matchedClients) {
        if (client.url.endsWith(OFFSCREEN_DOCUMENT_PATH)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: reading the docs, I still don't understand the use cases for `offscreen` API. Is this HTML injected into pages? why would you use offscreen instead of the regular `content.js` injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems: your code throws because there's no chrome.offscreen.hasDocument anymore, you can't use typescript directly as `Promise<boolean>` without compiling the code, and the example in the documentation is unnecessarily complicated.

All you need is a trivial try/catch:

```js
async function setupOffscreenDocument() {
  try {
    await chrome.offscreen.createDocument({
      url: 'offscreen.html',
      reasons: ['IFRAME_SCRIPTING'],
      justification: 'Listening to WebSocket messages',
    });
  } catch (error) {
    if (!error.message.startsWith('Only a single offscreen'))
      throw error;
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) I checked `chrome.offscreen.hasDocument` and it return true after offscreen created. 2) Typescript part because code from it. I forgot remove for this example.

Comment: hasDocument is an undocumented temporary method so don't use it in production, it'll be removed soon.